# Validation set overfiting and test accuracy increase

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

I'm using CNN for image classification. I build it from scratch because I have a small data set and this is a very specific task with no literature.

I got a test set of  700 data with 16 classes. When my validation set doesn't overfit (I stop it when loss = 1 then it'll start to increase) my accuracy (and other metrics like F1 score, precision, recall and confusion matrix) is lower compared to when I overfit my model (loss =2.5, train set accuracy =99%).

When I don't overfit my validation set I'm getting 70% accuracy and I climb to 80% when I overfit my model.

Is it a good strategy to use the overfitted model, Since I actually don't have more data to train or test my model on. But new data should be pretty similar to my actual test set.

Comment: Very difficult to tell without actually looking at the data. Does your validation data and test data resemble each other to an extent? You also can randomly pick wrongly classified images and see if the model is performing worse for a particular class and see if that class is in high proportion in the test set.

Comment: When the model doesn't over fit, most of my missclassification are assigned to class A. When I overfit class A become less important. I unfortunetely can't show data or even result. When I overfit, my model is doing very well excepting for few random image which are still classified into class A.

Comment: So I guess there are a lot of A in your data?

Comment: yes. I didn't says it but i'm using class weigts (with keras function and also tryied random value), it's improve performance; I used a long time ago downsampling on class A but it didn'tn work; since my model has chnage a lot i'll try to do it again

Comment: Yes, try downsampling / upsampling.